# Java execute Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java 8, and have the following Regular Expression:

https://regex101.com/r/XEgPWe/1

As you can see, it identifies numbers.

I am trying to implement a Java class that replaces values matched by the regex with the "X" character.

```
package com.jobs.spring.service;

public class ReplaceServiceImpl implements ReplaceService {

    private static final String REGEX_NUMBERS = "/\b(?:zero|nil|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixfteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|een|twee|drie|vier|fyf|ses|sewe|agt|nege|tien|iqanda|Kunye|Kubili|Kuthathu|Kune|Kuhlanu|Yisithupa|Yisikhombisa|Yisishiyagalombili|Yisishiyagalolunye|nnoto|nngwe|pedi|tharo|nne|hlano|tshelela|supa|robedi|robong|leshome|unothi|inye|zimbini|zintathu|zine|zintlanu|zintandathu|isixhenxe|sisibhozo|lithoba|cero|uno|dos|tres|cuatro|cinco|seis|siete|ocho|nueve|diez|Zéro|Un|Deux|Trois|Quatre|Cinq|Sept|Huit|Neuf|Dix|eins|zwei|drei|fünf|sechs|sieben|acht|neun|zehn|elf|[0-9])(?:.{0,10}(?:zero|nil|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|een|twee|drie|vier|fyf|ses|sewe|agt|nege|tien|iqanda|Kunye|Kubili|Kuthathu|Kune|Kuhlanu|Yisithupa|Yisikhombisa|Yisishiyagalombili|Yisishiyagalolunye|nnoto|nngwe|pedi|tharo|nne|hlano|tshelela|supa|robedi|robong|leshome|unothi|inye|zimbini|zintathu|zine|zintlanu|zintandathu|isixhenxe|sisibhozo|lithoba|cero|uno|dos|tres|cuatro|cinco|seis|siete|ocho|nueve|diez|Zéro|Un|Deux|Trois|Quatre|Cinq|Sept|Huit|Neuf|Dix|eins|zwei|drei|fünf|sechs|sieben|acht|neun|zehn|elf|[0-9])){4,}\b/gi";

    @Override
    public String removePII(String input) {
        input = input.replaceAll(REGEX_NUMBERS, "X");
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReplaceService rep = new ReplaceServiceImpl();
        System.out.println(rep.removePII("hello some text 1234567890 more.."));
    }

}
```

I would expect the output for be:

```
hello some text XXXXXXXXXX more..
```

but it is:

```
hello some text 1234567890 more..
```

From the [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/XEgPWe/1), my regex is correct, so I am probably doing something incorrect in my Java.

Any advise welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove `/` at the start and `/gi` at the end. Add `(?i)` at the start instead. And double backslashes.

Comment: Hi Wiktor Stribiżew, thanks for the advise. I tried removing the `/`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to double backslashes, too.

Comment: your regex uses a dialect I _believe_ (`/gi`), which is not suporrted by default. Verify your regex here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: You're using a string to populate the regex. There you _need_ to escape the `\ `. So eg `\d` becomes `\\d` ect ...

Comment: Just saying: your regex is hard to maintain. Try to setup an array and join them when setting up your regex string. By this, you only have to manipulate the array if you have to edit those number names.

Comment: Hi KarelG, good idea, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix several issues:

- remove regex delimiters (`/.../` with modifiers at the end)
- replace `/i` with the inline modifier version `(?i)` (or pass a `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` option to the `Matcher` instance)
- double the backslashes (as the regex escapes are formed with a literal `\`)

Use

```
private static final String REGEX_NUMBERS = "(?i)\\b(?:zero|nil|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixfteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|een|twee|drie|vier|fyf|ses|sewe|agt|nege|tien|iqanda|Kunye|Kubili|Kuthathu|Kune|Kuhlanu|Yisithupa|Yisikhombisa|Yisishiyagalombili|Yisishiyagalolunye|nnoto|nngwe|pedi|tharo|nne|hlano|tshelela|supa|robedi|robong|leshome|unothi|inye|zimbini|zintathu|zine|zintlanu|zintandathu|isixhenxe|sisibhozo|lithoba|cero|uno|dos|tres|cuatro|cinco|seis|siete|ocho|nueve|diez|Zéro|Un|Deux|Trois|Quatre|Cinq|Sept|Huit|Neuf|Dix|eins|zwei|drei|fünf|sechs|sieben|acht|neun|zehn|elf|[0-9])(?:.{0,10}(?:zero|nil|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|een|twee|drie|vier|fyf|ses|sewe|agt|nege|tien|iqanda|Kunye|Kubili|Kuthathu|Kune|Kuhlanu|Yisithupa|Yisikhombisa|Yisishiyagalombili|Yisishiyagalolunye|nnoto|nngwe|pedi|tharo|nne|hlano|tshelela|supa|robedi|robong|leshome|unothi|inye|zimbini|zintathu|zine|zintlanu|zintandathu|isixhenxe|sisibhozo|lithoba|cero|uno|dos|tres|cuatro|cinco|seis|siete|ocho|nueve|diez|Zéro|Un|Deux|Trois|Quatre|Cinq|Sept|Huit|Neuf|Dix|eins|zwei|drei|fünf|sechs|sieben|acht|neun|zehn|elf|[0-9])){4,}\\b";
```

Comment: Thank you that works. I will mark this as the correct answer in 6 min.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the wrong escape in Java. Your regex should be:

```
String regex = "\\b(?:zero|nil|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixfteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|een|twee|drie|vier|fyf|ses|sewe|agt|nege|tien|iqanda|Kunye|Kubili|Kuthathu|Kune|Kuhlanu|Yisithupa|Yisikhombisa|Yisishiyagalombili|Yisishiyagalolunye|nnoto|nngwe|pedi|tharo|nne|hlano|tshelela|supa|robedi|robong|leshome|unothi|inye|zimbini|zintathu|zine|zintlanu|zintandathu|isixhenxe|sisibhozo|lithoba|cero|uno|dos|tres|cuatro|cinco|seis|siete|ocho|nueve|diez|Zéro|Un|Deux|Trois|Quatre|Cinq|Sept|Huit|Neuf|Dix|eins|zwei|drei|fünf|sechs|sieben|acht|neun|zehn|elf|[0-9])(?:.{0,10}(?:zero|nil|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|een|twee|drie|vier|fyf|ses|sewe|agt|nege|tien|iqanda|Kunye|Kubili|Kuthathu|Kune|Kuhlanu|Yisithupa|Yisikhombisa|Yisishiyagalombili|Yisishiyagalolunye|nnoto|nngwe|pedi|tharo|nne|hlano|tshelela|supa|robedi|robong|leshome|unothi|inye|zimbini|zintathu|zine|zintlanu|zintandathu|isixhenxe|sisibhozo|lithoba|cero|uno|dos|tres|cuatro|cinco|seis|siete|ocho|nueve|diez|Zéro|Un|Deux|Trois|Quatre|Cinq|Sept|Huit|Neuf|Dix|eins|zwei|drei|fünf|sechs|sieben|acht|neun|zehn|elf|[0-9])){4,}\\b";
```